# upgrade broke in the middle - how to verify?

Tags: upgrade

I had to restart my laptop in the middle (after couple of hours) of upgrading from 12:04 to 12.10.

It seems like most of the things work ok, but some of the applications (such as Update manager), won't start.
BTW, I'm using wubi installer, which worked amazingly till now...

Is there a way to run some verification to check the system state? and finish the upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If most of the things work, then download the [Ubuntu 12.10 iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/), burn it to a DVD or USB and Upgrade again through the installer. It will offers you the option to reinstall Ubuntu 12.10.

[image]

Comment: will it work despite the fact I used the Windows installer?

Comment: No. You didn't mention in your question that you use the wubi installer. I don't know for Wubi installer. My answer is for a regular broken installation , not wubi.

Comment: Sorry originally when I wrote the question I thought there probably some check state utility that won't require any reinstillation.